# JavaScript Clone an inner HTML and then create new div based on that cloned text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

tricky situation.

I need to copy the inner html of 3 elements, from a `ul li a` selector and then inject a new div with the class name as the copied inner html

I manage to inject the element somewhat but I'm not close in doing what I need. 
https://jsfiddle.net/gt97vz51/1/

jQuery from the fiddle:

```
(function($) {
    $('ul > li').each(function(){
        var html = $(this).html();
        $(this).html('<span class="">' + html + '</span>' + html);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**This is the actual output I need:**

```
<ul> 
    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-default"><span class="name1"></span>name1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-default"><span class="name2"></span>name2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-default"><span class="name3"></span>name3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would prefer a JavaScript solution but if I can get a jQuery solution I'll still be super happy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the jQuery solution, depending on your desired output:

```js
(function($) {
  $('ul > li').each(function() {
    var className = $(this).find('a').text();
    $(this).find('a').prepend('<span class="' + className + '"></span>');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-default">name1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-default">name2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-default">name3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: would you mind showing me how Based on the above I would also add at the same time the .text class to the <a> element as well? the result would be : class="btn btn-default name2" etc etc.

Comment: just add `.addClass(className)` at the end of the second line. So it would be `$(this).find('a').prepend('<span class="' + className + '"></span>').addClass(className);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
(function($) {
$('ul > li a').each(function(){
    var html = $(this).html();
    $(this).prepend($('<span>', {'class':html}));
});
})(jQuery);
```